# mdates locators show non-existent time intervals in my graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, streamlit

I'm trying to build streamlit dashboard for stock marketting. My stock datas is between 9am to 16pm. I'm using locators for x-axis ticks. However, the chart shows the data for non-existent time intervals like in graph there is big gap between tciks and draw linear between 16pm to 9am. I want to remove this gap and make it continuous graph. How can I solve this problem. I tried to filter my data but it didn't work.

Here is my code and some example outputs.

```
def create_plot(name:str,label:str,title_info:str,data,period_var:str):
        fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

        ax1.set_ylabel(name)
        plt.xlabel('Datetime')
        plt.ylabel(label)
        plt.title(title_info)
        
        if period_var in ["1d"]:
            date_formatter = DateFormatter('%H:%M')
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))

        elif period_var in ["3d","5d"]:
            date_formatter = DateFormatter("%d-%H")
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(9,16),interval=2))
        elif period_var in ["1mo", "3mo", "6mo"]:
            date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y - %b")
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)

            ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=int(period_var[0])*2))
        elif period_var in ["1y", "2y", "5y"]:
            date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y-%b")
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=int(period_var[0])))
        else:
            date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y")
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
            ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
            

        ax1.plot(data.Date, data[name], label=name, marker='o', markersize=1)
        plt.xticks(rotation=45)
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.tight_layout()

        return fig
```

[image]
I'd be happy if anyone can help with that.

I tired to filter my data which is data["Date"] it doesn't work. I want to get rid of non-existent time intervals  which I don't have in my dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with ignoring DatetimeIndex and set new ticks.Here is last version of my code. If anyone will have same problem I hope it can be helpfull.

```
def create_plot(name: str, label: str, title_info: str, data, period_var: str):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8), sharex=True)

    data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
    ax1.set_ylabel(name)
    plt.xlabel('Datetime')
    plt.ylabel(label)
    plt.title(title_info)

    if period_var in ["1d"]:
        date_formatter = DateFormatter('%H:%M')
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))
        ax1.plot(data.index, data[name], label=name, marker='o', markersize=1)
        fill_green(data=data,name=name,ax1=ax1)

    elif period_var in ["3d", "5d"]:
        date_formatter = DateFormatter("%d-%H")
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(9, 16), interval=30))
        ax1.plot(range(data.index.size), data[name], label=name, marker='o', markersize=1)
        ymin = min(data[name])
        ymax = max(data[name])
        padding = 0.05 * (ymax - ymin) 
        ax1.set_ylim(ymin - padding, ymax + padding)


        ax1.fill_between(range(data.index.size), data[name], color='green', alpha=0.3)

        ticks_date = data.index.indexer_at_time('08:00')
        ticks_time = np.arange(data.index.size)[data.index.minute == 0][::2] 
        ax1.set_xticks(ticks_date)
        ax1.set_xticks(ticks_time, minor=True)

        labels_date = [maj_tick.strftime('\n%d-%b').replace('\n0', '\n')
                       for maj_tick in data.index[ticks_date]]
        labels_time = [min_tick.strftime('%d %I %p').lstrip('0').lower()
                       for min_tick in data.index[ticks_time]]
        ax1.set_xticklabels(labels_date)
        ax1.set_xticklabels(labels_time, minor=True)

    elif period_var in ["1mo", "3mo", "6mo"]:
        date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y - %b")
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
        ax1.plot(data.index, data[name], label=name, marker='o', markersize=1)
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=int(period_var[0]) * 2))
        fill_green(data=data,name=name,ax1=ax1)
    elif period_var in ["1y", "2y", "5y"]:
        date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y-%b")
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=int(period_var[0])))
        ax1.plot(data.index, data[name], label=name, marker='o', markersize=1)
        fill_green(data=data,name=name,ax1=ax1)
    else:
        date_formatter = DateFormatter("%Y")
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
        ax1.plot(data.index, data[name], label=name, marker='o', markersize=1)
        fill_green(data=data,name=name,ax1=ax1)
        
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.tight_layout()

    return fig
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to `reindex` your filtered dataframe with the original indexing, creating NaN records for those times you don't want to plot.

MVCE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(2_000), 
                  index=pd.date_range('2021-10-03 07:00:00', 
                                      periods=2_000, freq='T'), 
                  columns=['value'])

dfs = df.between_time('09:00','15:00')

dfs.reindex(df.index).plot()
```

Output:
[image]

Versus without re-indexing:

```
dfs.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your work but I want to remove this gap and build continuous graph

Comment: I have solved my problem with ignoring DatetimeIndex and set new tick with using range.